# How to get a smooth result with RSM (Reflective Shadow Mapping)?

Tags: c++, 3d, vulkan

I'm trying to implement a Reflective Shadow Mapping program with Vulkan.
The problem is that a get bad result :
[image: rsm_error]

As you can see the result is not smooth.

Here I am rendering in a first pass the position, normal and flux from the light position in 3 textures with a resolution of 512 * 512.

In a second pass, I compute the indirect illumination from the first pass textures according to this paper (http://www.klayge.org/material/3_12/GI/rsm.pdf) :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 151; i++)
{
    vec4 rsmProjCoords = projCoords + vec4(rsmDiskSampling[i] * 0.09, 0.0, 0.0);

    vec3 indirectLightPos = texture(rsmPosition, rsmProjCoords.xy).rgb;
    vec3 indirectLightNorm = texture(rsmNormal, rsmProjCoords.xy).rgb;
    vec3 indirectLightFlux = texture(rsmFlux, rsmProjCoords.xy).rgb;

    vec3 r = worldPos - indirectLightPos;
    float distP2 = dot( r, r ); 

    vec3 emission = indirectLightFlux * (max(0.0, dot(indirectLightNorm, r)) * max(0.0, dot(N, -r)));
    emission *= rsmDiskSampling[i].x * rsmDiskSampling[i].x / (distP2 * distP2);        

    indirectRSM += emission;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed.

The main problem was the sampling, I was using a linear sampling instead of a nearest sampling :

```
samplerInfo.magFilter = VK_FILTER_NEAREST;
samplerInfo.minFilter = VK_FILTER_NEAREST;
```

Other problems were the number of VPL used and the distance between them.